# Pick and place robot

Tags: robotic-arm, matlab

I have to simulate a pick and place robot (3 DOF). I tried with MATLAB. It should pick and place different objects according to their geometry.

Where can I find similar m-codes and algorithms?

Comment: What did you try? What wasn't working? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I voted to close this question as "unclear what you're asking." As @SteveO hints at in his answer, there doesn't appear to be any specific problem.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Kadir Karadag. On stack exchange, questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please edit your question to add this information. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your question that you are only simulating the robot's kinematics, and not dynamics or controls.   However, this recommendation would be the same even if you had to complete a full-up controls simulation, also.

Why don't you work out the mathematical equations of the robot (forward kinematics) then invert them manually?  Then write m-code to simulate the robot?

This will teach you so much more about locating objects geometrically into the workspace and having the robot grasp them, than you would learn by copying others' m-codes.   When you get stuck, we will be happy to answer specific questions you encounter.

Comment: I agree -- the question has to be much more specific. But, regarding 3-DOF kinematics, I'd recommend reading Robot Modeling and Control by Mark W. Spong. He shows derivations for 3DOF FK and IK (Coming up with nice forms for the IK would be tricky without a guide.)

Comment: Yes, Spong's book, or Craig's, or Paul's would help a lot.   I assumed since this seemed like an assignment that the background material was provided.  But if not, your point is a good one.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. I would like to such a animation like this simulate (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsJ4c4dgGH0) and (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3C6K_iJM0M) i will  crate roboter with lines ? how should i start ?